# Xpath query exclude ancestors of a particular namespace

Tags: xpath

The following xpath query gets nodes except where the ancestor is a particular type:

```
(/def:Image|…|//def:TextBox)[not(ancestor::clpm:EditableText)]
```

However, I want to be able to exclude all nodes that have an ancestor that is in the `clpm` namespace.

Can't work it out guys, any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use the following as predicate:

> **not(ancestor::*[starts-with(name(),'clpm:')])**

**Do note**, however, that `namespace` and `prefix` are quite different things. In a single XML document many different prefixes may be bound to the same namespace and a single prefix may be bound (redefined) to more than one namespace.

In your question you say `namespace`, when you mean `prefix`.

The XPath expression above is true if the current node doesn't have any ancestors with **`prefix`** clpm.